# How to get wix bootstrapper to start extracting installer immediately

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

My installer has a license dialog, so I don't see the need to display one in the bootstrapper.  This [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978501/how-to-create-a-bootstrapper-application-without-a-license-agreement-step) had an answer which doesn't display the license agreement, but still requires the user to click the install button.   I'd like to immediately extract and run .msi without requiring any user input.  Is there a way to skip the dialog completely?

Answer (score 0):

There is option called `/passive` which should do what you want: start installation automatically, showing the user interface.

However, the problem is that it can't be set by default - you'd have to wrap your .msi into some kind of .exe which calls the msi with specific command line.

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-Launch-using-passive-option-as-default-td7591613.html