# Wix Bootstrapper without License UI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8

I need some help to create a WiX Bootstrapper without the license UI. I have a WiX MSI setup which has all screens like: Welcome, License, Destination Folder and Progress UI.

This MSI should run through Bootstrap.exe using WiX Bundle. When I run this, I can see two license screens - one is Bootstrapper and another is my MSI screen. So how can I eliminate / hide bootstrapper license UI.

Is there a way to run install directly without clicking install button in Bootstrapper UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootstrapper application without a license agreement step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978501/how-to-create-a-bootstrapper-application-without-a-license-agreement-step)

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE**: Simpler approach then Custom Bootstrapper Application (described below).
>
> ***Blank Hyperlink URL***: It seems there is a simple workaround whilst still using the Standard Bootstrapper Application. You can
>   specify a blank URL for the license:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

  <Bundle Name="MyTestApp" Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="Someone" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" /> <!--Blank URL-->
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="Installer.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>

</Wix>
```

> ***Direct Install***: I do not know of a way to invoke the install directly without clicking the install button, short of running the
>   whole bundle silently without a GUI at all.

---

***Prerequisites?***: Do you need the bootstrapper to install prerequisites, or do you just want to wrap your MSI in a **`setup.exe`**? You can create setup.exe files using some other tools as well (Zip tools, VS Installer Projects, etc...).

***Rationale***: I am not aware of a way to hide the bootstrapper license dialog when you use the standard bootstrapper application. I believe the idea is that all MSI's are supposed to run in silent mode kicked off by the bootstrapper, and hence the license dialogs of each setup is hidden.

***Custom Bootstrapper Application***: I haven't really tried this, but you can create your own bootstrapper application - the application that runs the setup.exe GUI - and then you can hide the license dialog. The only sample I can think of right now is [Rainer Stropek's sample here](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/CustomBurnUI). Not much to go on, but the best I got at the moment. This is a simple sample with very basic GUI.